# css setting background repeat step

Tags: css, canvas, background-image

I'm creating a web-editor and created a 32x32 pixel background image for the canvas. 
I want to use different dynamic grid sizes for the editor, for eg. 8x8, 16x16, 32x32.
So I need to set the background repeat size through css.
Any ideas if it's possible to set the background repeat size? 
I'd like to avoid creating several background-image and classes.
Thanks!

Comment: Can't you put the editor in a div that varies in width and then just add a background to that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use background-size in % for eg. `background-size: 10%;` And if you are targeting different sizes use @media rule and increase/decrease the percentage.

Comment: thanks, i've tried that, unfortunately the browser will start stretching and the black pixel turns into grey .. :/

Comment: If you use same percentage value then you'll get same grid view and also you don't have to use @media rules and this would be better for your editor.